# Nginx: Remove part of the url

Tags: url, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm looking for the right rewrite rule for my Nginx server. I would like to remove a specific part of the URL.

An Example:

example.com/assets/files   *-- the real location*

to

example.com/files

and

example.com/assets/files/image.jpg

to

example.com/files/image.jpg

and

example.com/assets/themes/css/style.css

to

example.com/themes/css/style.css

I have googled it, but none of the salutations I found worked for me. I just got some 500 errors.

So what rewrite rule do I need and where should I put it in my conf file. Thank you!

Comment: Real location is a path on disk. Still unclear what you want

Comment: I have a file here: **example.com/assets/files/image.jpg**
And I want it to remove assets from the URL.
Make it like this: **example.com/files/image.jpg**

Answer (score 1):

According to what you have posted in question. I can figure out that you are try to rename your URL, without changing the exact location of the file.

For achieving this, add these in your server directive:

```
#Example : 
#Rewriting example.com/themes -> example.com/assets/themes
location /themes {
    rewrite ^/.* http://$server_name/assets/themes permanent;
}
location /files {
    rewrite ^/.* http://$server_name/assets/files permanent;
}
```

Now your user would be opening for eg: http://example.com/files/image.jpg, and your file on server would be placed at location /var/www/..something.../example.com/assets/files/image.jpg

*Hope this helps..! :)*

Comment: Thank you! It works like halfway, if I go to /files I get redirected to /assets/files. But /files/image.png gives me a 404 error. I posted my config here http://pastebin.com/70tijHRz if It's easier to solve.

Comment: This conf redirects me to /assets/files/files. /files/image.png gives me a 404. I forgot one location block I have for wordpress. Does this effect my config? NEW config --> http://pastebin.com/j7M648KF